# Why does my for loop print the list n times?

Tags: python, pandas

Please don't get me wrong on this one, i really want to understand it.
So i have 157 Data Entries which is always the first day (Energy Value) of every month.
And when i print it out there are 157 Entries indeed.

But when i put it in a for loop it prints it out 157x157 times, hopee i sayed that right.
Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import logging

# set working directory
os.chdir("Path to CSVs")

# Define Logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.info('Start of program')
# find all csv files in the folder
# use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
# save result in list -> all_filenames
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
# logging.info('Found ' + all_filenames.count() + 'CSVs')

# combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_filenames])
logging.info('Combining all CSVs into one....')
# Transform Timestamp column into datetime
combined_csv['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_csv.Timestamp)
logging.info('Transforming Timestamps into datetime....')
# Read out first day and last day of every day of every month
combined_csv = combined_csv.resample('D', on='Timestamp')['HtmDht_Energy'].agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
logging.info('Reading out data entries for the first and last day of every month....')
combined_csv['Tag'] = combined_csv.Timestamp.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"] = combined_csv["first"]
combined_csv["Zählerstand Ende"] = combined_csv["last"]


for i in combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"]:
 print("Zählerstand Beginn(kWh/Tag): " + str(i) + " " + combined_csv['Tag'])


#for x in zE:
 # print("Zählerstand Ende(kWh/Tag): " + str(x) + " " + combined_csv['Tag'])


# print(combined_csv["Zählerstand Ende"])
# Convert Timestamp into needed format
logging.info('Converting Timestamps into needed Format....')
#print('Name der Solaranlage:')
#solarAnlageName = input()
logging.info('Exporting Excel File for Counter Reading....')
#plotly.offline.plot(dailyYield, filename="DailyYieldReport.html")
logging.info('Done')
# export as excel file
# combined_csv.to_excel('energy_data.xlsx', index=False)
logging.info('End of Program')
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Data Entries"*? Rows in your dataframe? Files to read? Also, what code (loop) do you use to print what variable?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific and yes - i mean the rows in my dataframe. I use the for loop "for i in combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"]:
 print("Zählerstand Beginn(kWh/Tag): " + str(i) + " " + combined_csv['Tag'])"

Comment: ok so for each element in one column you print the whole other column (`combined_csv['Tag']`), is that intended? Or do you want to print a specific element from that column?

Comment: are you looking for `for v, d in zip(combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"], combined_csv['Tag']): print(f"Zählerstand Beginn(kWh/Tag): {v} {d}")`?

Comment: So what i want to do is print the Energy Column which is  "combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"]" plus the day which is "combined_csv['Tag']"

Comment: glad I could help; so basically you want to iterate both columns element-wise. `zip` is very helpful in such cases.